# JSON形式で、項目を追加していく方法

Tags: ios, json

JSON形式において、項目を追加していく方法についての質問です。
iOSのContentBlock機能を想定しています。

例えば、"url-filter"に対応するurlを追加していくには、
どのように記載すればよいのでしょうか。

```
[
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "xvideos.com"
        }
    }
]
```

"xvideos.com"だけでなく、[http://wgen.kodansha.ne.jp/も](http://wgen.kodansha.ne.jp/%E3%82%82)"url-filter"に追加しようと
下記のように記載したところ、JSONチェッカーで「Fail21: 予期しない文字[が見つかりました。 [ <- ?」とエラーが返されました。
http://webtool.morinkey.net/json.html

```
[
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "xvideos.com"
        }
    }
]
[
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "http://wgen.kodansha.ne.jp/"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSONをどう解釈するか、仕様が不明なままでの回答になりますが、最初に提示されたものの意図からすると、次のようにするのかなーと

```
[
    {
        "action": {
        "type": "block"
        },
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "xvideos.com"
        }
    },   
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": "http://wgen.kodansha.ne.jp/"
        }
    }
]
```